# Entity with List in Select statement

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Beginning to think the below is not possible due to errors and lack of supporting evidence in logic but wanted to confirm.

We're using LINQ to build an entity SQL statement but need to use a List in the Select statement to gather additional data. This data is from a previous Entity collection in app memory. Doing the same thing straight up with Entity works without issue.

The pseudo-code looks like:

```
List<ParticipationStatus> lstStatuses = GetStatuses();

var data = (
    from user in dbContext.User
    where user.JoinDate >= *date*
    select new CustomObject 
    {
        Name = user.FullName,
        ParticipationStatus = lstStatuses
            .Where(m => m.ParticipationStatusID == user.ParticipationStatusID)
            .Select(x => x.Label)
            .FirstOrDefault() + " Some string here"
    } )
    .ToList();
```

Just wanted some confirmation of this possibility.

Comment: The bigger issue is that you're performing two queries that should be one. The query performed by `GetStatuses` should be composed into this one. Make one trip to the database instead of two.

Comment: You should use a `Join` instead.

Comment: Do you have navigation-properties defined on `User` to `ParticipationStatus`?

Comment: Is `CustomObject` compatible with Linq? Depending on how you're using EF, you might not be able to instantiate non-entity types in a `.Select` step within the `IQueryable` part, but you can after the query is materialized.

Comment: lstStatuses is already in memory and used so the join isn't needed. Please read the full question beforehand. Thank you.

Comment: @Ringo64 I did, and you're being unnecessarily dismissive. EF handles redundant data-loading perfectly fine, by-design. Furthermore, you can do a `Join` for in-memory objects _after_ loading your `Users`.

Comment: Thanks @DAI, it is compatible with EF. We actually use this elsewhere without issue.

Comment: @DAI, I'm not trying to be dismissive, just trying to get an answer to the original question. If the answer is no, you need to use a JOIN, I'm happy to accept that answer.

Comment: `without issue` you mean you didn't notice the problems yet, or ignored the performance problems. There's no need for such subqueries or JOINs if the entities have proper relations. Dai's answer shows how easy the query is in that case

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `ParticipationStatus` navigation-property set-up, all you need is this:

```
var usersWithStatus = await dbContext.Users
    .Where( u => u.JoinDate >= someDateTime )
    .Select( u => new CustomObject
    {
        Name = u.FullName,
        ParticipationStatus = u.ParticipationStatus.Label + " Some string here"
    } )
    .ToListAsync();
```

If you *really* want to re-use your existing `List<ParticipationStatus> lstStatuses = GetStatuses();` (which I think is a bad idea: because as far as we can see, there is no guarantee that `lstStatuses` actually contains every `ParticipationStatus` referneced by every `User`, and your code dopesn't appear to be using a transaction to ensure isolated or consistent reads), but you can do the `Join` in-memory after loading users:

```
List<ParticipationStatus> lstStatuses = GetStatuses();

List<User> users = await dbContext.Users
    .Where( u => u.JoinDate >= someDateTime )
    .ToListAsync();

List<CustomObject> usersWithStatus = users
    .Join(
        inner: lstStatuses,
        outerKeySelector: u => u.ParticipationStatusID,
        innerKeySelector: s => s.ParticipationStatusID,
        resultSelector: ( u, s ) => new CustomObject
        {
            Name = u.FullName,
            ParticipationStatus = s.Label + " Some string here"
        }
    )
    .ToList();
```

- Linq's `Join` is an `INNER JOIN` operation (and not any other kind of join, like `FULL OUTER JOIN`). Note that, as with SQL's `INNER JOIN`, it is possible for multiple rows in `inner` and `outer` to match each-other which may be undesirable.

  - And if any `User` entities aren't matched to a `lstStatuses` item then that `User` will be silently excluded from the results - whereas I'd consider that *exceptional* and if this were my program I'd want it to throw an exception instead of silently excluding it.
- Internally, the `.Join` will efficiently map `User` and `ParticipationStatus` in linear-time `O(n[u] + n[s])` by using a temporary hashtable, whereas your current code takes quadratic time: `O(n[u] * n[s])`.

Comment: I suspect `ParticipationStatus` is an enum, so the lookup into `lstStatuses` could be replaced either with the proper enum description or a lookup *after* loading the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It won't be an `enum` because the OP's code shows them accessing the member-property `ParticipationStatus.ParticipationStatusID` - though it's probably an "`enum`-stored-in-a-table" - which I'm not a fan of.